# PHPStorm - Suggestions in included HTML

Tags: php, html, phpstorm

I can not see suggestion for variable `$data` in `Default.phtml` if I include HTML file `Default.phtml` from class `Code_Controller.php` method.
Here is a code example.

Code_Controller:

```
abstract class Core_Controller{
    protected $template;

    public function display(){
        $data['title']  = 'Title of site';

        if(Core_Config::$is_admin){
            require_once ADMIN_TEMPLATES_PATH . $this->template . '.phtml';
        }else{
            require_once PUBLIC_TEMPLATES_PATH . $this->template . '.phtml';
        }
    }
}
```

Default.phtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $data['title'] ?></title>
</head>

<body>
    The content of the document......
</body>

</html>
```

Have anybody some idea?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Standard approach in such case: use PHPDoc and declare that variable there (at the top of the file), e.g.

```
<?php
/** @var array $data */
?>
...HTML CODE HERE...
```

Comment: Thanks that works great. But is any different options if i dont want to define a variables in PHTML file?

Comment: I know no other options .. unless you write custom plugin that will do deep analysis of your code/framework somehow  (or whatever other options you will code there) and will do such "variable declaration" magic for you.

Comment: Surely, you can try defining such variables as globals in separate file (may work) .. but then it will affect ALL files and not that specific file only.